# iOS 15.5 > iCloud has two different options for Photos

Tags: photos, ios, icloud

In iOS **version 15.5** `Settings > Your name > iCloud` there are two different options for Photos.

A Photos option at the top which opens more options, and another Photos option below you can only check/uncheck.

What’s the purpose of this second option?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see the second option, only the first. What device is this?

Comment: The device in question is my iPad. I have checked my iPhone 8 and it has the two options as well.

Comment: I *believe* that the second options toggles photos.app's use of iCloud (use or **don't** use iCloud for photos) whereas the first options seem to be what part of photos will be used on iCloud. However I am guessing here, so it's not an answer, rather a comment.

Comment: Checked 2 phones & an iPad, 2 different users, none of them have that second switch.

Comment: Added a picture of the iPhone where you can see the switch option.

Comment: I checked on a friend’s iPad with iOS 15.0.2 and that second option doesn’t exist. So, it’s something that appeared in newer iOS versions…

Comment: All three devices I checked were running 15.5.

Comment: What a mystery!